# Get collection items from external site within sharepoint site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, spservices

I need to get all items of a list in my Sharepoint site. So I used this snippet :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Announcements",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
          $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
          });
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
    <ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

Which uses [SPServices javascript Library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems) . It works fine, but I need to edit this method to get items **from another site** which I have the permission to access to.

So How can I accomplish this task ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to add the `webURL` part of it as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $().SPServices({
         operation: "GetListItems",
         webURL: "https://www.myweburlgoeshere.com",
         async: false,
         listName: "Announcements",
         CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
         completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
                $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
            });
         }
    });
});
```